# Messed up my macOS system package with pip package

Tags: python, macos, pip

I messed up my decencies system package with installing package like tensor-flow, python , numpy and jupyter without isolating or using environment for each decencies. How can i restore all of the things to default when you got your first mac without losing data

Comment: I'm sorry to say it, but from my many many years of experience, the only way to know you're 100% back to the original setup and behavior, is to install a fresh OS. - you might be able to hack on your system and get it back to pretty much working, but you can't "restore all of the things to default when you got your first mac" without a full wipe and reinstall.

Comment: If you have a place to save off your old system, this isn't that big a deal.  When you install the new OS, the installer will ask you if you want to restore data from an old installation.  If you point the installer at your old volume, it is pretty good about restoring anything that existed just for individual users.

Comment: ...oh...and I assume you wouldn't be asking this if you had a recent Time Machine backup.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1):

What is messed up ? Just your Python Env inside the Mac ?

Assuming that the Mac O.S. is OK ....  If you O.S. is screwed up ... sorry reformat/time-machine etc.

Using Python3.6.....

```sh
python3.6 -m venv ~/.pe36
alias pe36="~/.pe36/bin/activate"
pe36
pip3 install xxxx
```

Add the alias **pe36** to your .bash_profile

When you log in - to work in your python environment just type  *pe36* and carry on.

Hope that helps.